# How multiple developer can work on same feature branch gerrit

Tags: github, gerrit

I am newbie using Gerrit review flow and previously had good experience in GitHub and GitLab.
But looks Gerrit review system works bit different.
So I have created one feature branch called feature/test. This branch contains one test commit and this commit has been pushed to Gerrit.
Change can be seen Gerrit with unique change id and commit.

Now the problem is, on this feature branch 3 developers will work and they need to continuously fetch each other changes with same change id.

Can someone help on this, what I need to do. because when I pulled this feature branch with one test commit then change is not visible to me at different place.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you mean by "fetch each other changes WITH SAME CHANGE ID". A Change-Id is a unique number that identifies a change in Gerrit.  Each change made by each developer will have different Change-Ids.

The better process to work on Gerrit is the following:

1- Update the local repository

```
git fetch
```

2- Create a work branch based on the remote branch:

```
git checkout -b work1 origin/feature/test
```

3- Make your change and commit

```
git add
git commit
```

4- Push your change to review on Gerrit:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature/test
```

If the reviewer suggests something to do:

1- Checkout the work branch

```
git checkout work1
```

2- Fix your change and commit

```
git add
git commit --amend
```

3- Push the fix to Gerrit:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature/test
```

All developers can work in parallel using the same process. You can also work in parallel by creating other work branches (work2, work3, etc) while is waiting for review. Avoid serializing the commits by always basing your work branches in the remote branch and not in your previous work branch.

When the feature branch is read, it can be merged in the master (main, release, or whatever it is called) branch.